# C# port of data mining algorithm much slower than reference implementation

Tags: c#, performance, matrix, clustering, data-mining

I was trying to implement the algorithm specified in [this research paper](http://phoebe.inf.upol.cz/~havrlanl/articles/Vychodil08_Anafcfc.pdf) (please ignore the math, since it's irrelevant to the question). This algorithm is very basic in formal concept analysis. The input is supposed to be an NxM matrix and a list of lists or array of lists as you can see in the paper section 3.1. In fact, for simulation purposes, I use a simple .cxt file for representing the objects and their attributes as shown here (this is a very simple example).

This C# implementation performs the worst in comparison to the author's C++ implementation. The author offers a stand alone .exe file programmed in C++ and it's at least 35 times faster. Why? How can I improve this code?

```
XXX...
X.XXXX
XX..X.
.XX...
```

Each row represents an object with the attributes it has `X` or has not `.`. My implementation is very straightforward where I just read the .cxt file and store the values as `. -> 0` and `X -> 1` then proceed to the implementation of the two procedures illustrated in the pseudocode.

C# implementation:

```
public void generate_from(int[] B, int y)
        {
            int[] D;
            Total_Concepts++;
            //for (int i = 0; i < B.Length; i++)
            //    if (B[i] == 1)
            //        Console.Write(i+",");
            //Console.WriteLine();
                if (y < CT_WIDTH)
                {
                    for (int j = y; j < CT_WIDTH; j++)
                    {
                        if (B[j] == 0)
                        {
                            B[j] = 1;
                            D = compute_closure(B, j);
                            bool skip = false;
                            for (int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                            {
                                if (D[k] != B[k])
                                {
                                    skip = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (!skip)
                                generate_from(D, j + 1);
                            B[j] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        int[] compute_closure(int[] B, int y)
        {
            bool match;
            int[] D = new int[CT_WIDTH];
            for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH; j++)
                D[j] = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < rows[y].Count; i++)
            {
                match = true;
                for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH; j++)
                {
                    if (B[j] == 1 && FCAContext[rows[y][i] * CT_WIDTH + j] == 0)
                    {
                        match = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (match)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH; j++)
                        if (FCAContext[rows[y][i] * CT_WIDTH + j] == 0)
                            D[j] = 0;
                }
            }
            return D;
        }
```

For tracing to the code, I form the input in the following manner:

```
        public int Total_Concepts = 0;
        // Total Number of Attributes : TABLE-WIDTH , Total Number of Objects : TABLE-HEIGHT
        int CT_WIDTH, CT_HEIGHT; 
        // The Cross Table
        int[] FCAContext = new int[5000000];
        // The Second representation
        List<int>[] rows = new List<int>[1000];
        public alg(int Context_Width, int Context_Height, string SampleData)
        {
            CT_WIDTH = Context_Width;
            CT_HEIGHT = Context_Height;

            string instance;
            int FCACC = 0;
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(SampleData))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < CT_HEIGHT; i++)
                {
                    instance = file.ReadLine();
                    for (int j = 0; j < CT_WIDTH; j++)
                        if (instance[j] == 'X')
                        {
                            FCAContext[FCACC] = 1;
                            FCACC++;
                        }
                        else
                            if (instance[j] == '.')
                            {
                                FCAContext[FCACC] = 0;
                                FCACC++;
                            }
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < CT_WIDTH; i++)
            {
                rows[i]= new List<int>();
                for (int j = 0; j < CT_HEIGHT; j++)
                    if (FCAContext[j * CT_WIDTH + i] == 1)
                        rows[i].Add(j);
            }


        }
```

Moreover, the calling to all this class of algorithm is:

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int w = 126;
            int h = 8124;
            // Mushroom 8124 X 126
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            alg fca = new alg(w, h, @"C:\FCA\mushroom.txt");
            fca.generate_from(new int[w], 0, new int[1000000]);
            //fca.generate_from(new int[w], 0);
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Total Concepts Generated : " + fca.Total_Concepts);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Computation Time : " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: [Cross-posted from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31553993/1157100)

Comment: One possible reason for the difference in speed is, it appears, from his [source code](http://fcalgs.sourceforge.net/), he's using multi-threading.